# Moq SetUp.Return not working for repository mock

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, nunit, moq, repository-pattern

I am trying to mock my repository's Get() method to return an object in order to fake an update on that object, but my setup is not working:

Here is my Test:

```
[Test]
public void TestUploadDealSummaryReportUploadedExistingUpdatesSuccessfully()
{
    var dealSummary = new DealSummary {FileName = "Test"};
    _mockRepository.Setup(r => r.Get(x => x.FileName == dealSummary.FileName))
        .Returns(new DealSummary {FileName = "Test"}); //not working for some reason...

    var reportUploader = new ReportUploader(_mockUnitOfWork.Object, _mockRepository.Object);
    reportUploader.UploadDealSummaryReport(dealSummary, "", "");

    _mockRepository.Verify(r => r.Update(dealSummary));
    _mockUnitOfWork.Verify(uow => uow.Save());
}
```

Here is the method that is being tested:

```
public void UploadDealSummaryReport(DealSummary dealSummary, string uploadedBy, string comments)
{
    dealSummary.UploadedBy = uploadedBy;
    dealSummary.Comments = comments;

    // method should be mocked to return a deal summary but returns null
    var existingDealSummary = _repository.Get(x => x.FileName == dealSummary.FileName);
    if (existingDealSummary == null)
        _repository.Insert(dealSummary);
    else
        _repository.Update(dealSummary);

    _unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

And here is the error that I get when I run my unit test:

> Moq.MockException : 
>   Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: r => r.Update(.dealSummary)
>   No setups configured.
>
> Performed invocations:
>   IRepository`1.Get(x => (x.FileName == value(FRSDashboard.Lib.Concrete.ReportUploader+<>c__DisplayClass0).dealSummary.FileName))
>   IRepository`1.Insert(FRSDashboard.Data.Entities.DealSummary)
>   at Moq.Mock.ThrowVerifyException(MethodCall expected, IEnumerable`1 setups, IEnumerable`1 actualCalls, Expression expression, Times times, Int32 callCount)
>   at Moq.Mock.VerifyCalls(Interceptor targetInterceptor, MethodCall expected, Expression expression, Times times)
>   at Moq.Mock.Verify(Mock mock, Expression`1 expression, Times times, String failMessage)
>   at Moq.Mock`1.Verify(Expression`1 expression)
>   at FRSDashboard.Test.FRSDashboard.Lib.ReportUploaderTest.TestUploadDealSummaryReportUploadedExistingUpdatesSuccessfully

Through debugging I have found that the **x => x.FileName** is returning null, but even if i compare it to null I still get a null instead of the Deal Summary I want returned. Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm guessing your setup isn't matching the call you make because they're two different anonymous lambdas. You may needs something like

```
_mockRepository.Setup(r => r.Get(It.IsAny<**whatever your get lambda is defined as**>()).Returns(new DealSummary {FileName = "Test"});
```

You could verify by setting a breakpoint in the Get() method of your repository and seeing if it is hit. It shouldn't be.

Comment: Thank you, when I updated my code to `_mockRepository.Setup(r => r.Get(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<DealSummary, bool>>>())).Returns(new DealSummary { FileName = "Test" });` the test passed.